# Why does var_dump returns null in php code?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am currently developing a custom CMS using PHP and MySQL.

I am creating a hook system and I have created one too. The hook system works fine but today I got a null value while I used var_dump on execution of hook.

My hook class is as under:

```
<?php
/**
 * Hooks Class
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

class Hooks
{

    private $hooks;

    function __construct() {
        $this->hooks = [];
    }
    
    function add_event( $where, $callback, $priority = 50 ) {
        if ( !isset( $this->hooks[$where] ) ) {
            $this->hooks[$where] = [];
        }
        $this->hooks[$where][$callback] = $priority;
    }

    function remove_event( $where, $callback ) {
        if ( isset( $this->hooks[$where][$callback] ) ) {
            unset( $this->hooks[$where][$callback] );
        }
    }

    function is_event( $where ) {
        if ( isset( $this->hooks[$where] ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    function execute( $where, $args = [] ) {
        if ( isset( $this->hooks[$where] ) && is_array( $this->hooks[$where] ) ) {
            arsort( $this->hooks[$where] );
            foreach ( $this->hooks[$where] as $callback => $priority ) {
                call_user_func_array( $callback, $args );
            }
        }
    }

}

$hooks_class = new Hooks;

function add_event( $where, $callback, $priority = 50 ) {
    global $hooks_class;
    if ( isset( $hooks_class ) ) {
        $hooks_class->add_event( $where, $callback, $priority );
    }    
}

function remove_event( $where, $callback ) {
    global $hooks_class;
    if ( isset( $hooks_class ) ) {
        $hooks_class->remove_event( $where, $callback );
    }
}

function is_event( $where ) {
    global $hooks_class;
    if ( isset( $hooks_class ) ) {
        $hooks_class->is_event( $where );
    }
}
    
function execute_event( $where, $args = [] ) {
    global $hooks_class;
    if ( isset( $hooks_class ) ) {
        $hooks_class->execute( $where, $args );
    }
}
```

Now I am executing the hook and var_dump returns NULL I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_body_class' ) ) {
    function get_body_class( $custom = '' ) {
        $classes = [];
        $page = get_current_script_name( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], true );
        $classes[] = $page;
        if ( !empty( $custom ) ) {
            $classes[] = $custom;
        }
        if ( !empty( $classes ) ) {
            return 'class="' . implode( ' ', $classes ) . '"';
        }
    }
}

if ( !function_exists( 'login_page_body_classes' ) ) {
    function login_page_body_classes() {
        $custom = '';
        if ( is_login_page() ) {
            $custom .= 'page bg-gradient-to-b from-purple-600 via-purple-600 to-blue-900 text-white';
        }
        return $custom;
    }
    add_event( '_body_class', 'login_page_body_classes' );
}

var_dump( execute_event( '_body_class' ) );
```

My question is why does it not return the classes stored in $custom variable?

Comment: `function execute_event( $where, $args = [] )` has no return value.

Comment: Neither does `is_event`. They should both use `return $hooks_class->...`

Comment: Nor does the class method `function execute( $where, $args = [] )` that `execute_event()` calls.

Comment: `execute_event()` will call `function login_page_body_classes()` and it reutrns $custom variable. What am I missing?

Comment: If you want the events to return values, then you must return them in all functions/methods all the way down the chain. If A calls B that calls C and C returns a value, then B needs to return the response of C and A needs to return the response from B and so on.

Comment: Well that resolved my issue. Thank you so much.